# AWS Lambda Thumbor Image processing gifsicle not found

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, aws-lambda, thumbor

I have been trying to work with aws lambda image processing I have been using the following code
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler

I want to use gifsicle and the tool used in the code is Thumbor python package which has an option to enable gifsicle.

I have compiled gifsicle and attaching the same in the lambda function package.

What I cannot do is make thumbor pick gifsicle from a perticular path as it tries to get it from the OS path.

Is there a way I can set the OS Path with gifsicle binary location before the function is run.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Its been fixed by the AWS team You can take a new pull and check